# Preventing browser from reacting to keydown-event, but without canceling the event

Tags: javascript, events

In my JavaScript I need to catch keyboard events.
However, when certain keys are pressed, the browser has a certain action like for example going to the previous page if backspace is pressed, or scrolling to the bottom of the page if the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> is pressed.

I can stop these browser-actions by for example catching the `keydown` event and call `event.preventDefault()`. However, if I call `event.preventDefault()` on the `keydown` event the `keypress` and `keyup` events never occur.

I need to be able to block default browser behavior for `keydown` events, and still catch the same keys when they are released. How can I do this?

Comment: just add conditions in the event. If it's a key you don't want the browser to respond to use preventDefault() otherwise don't or vise versa.

Comment: If you handled the event in `keydown`, why do you want to capture the event again in `keyup`? You could just call your `keyup` handler explicitly from `keydown` if you really want.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. http://jsfiddle.net/amaan/C42hz/

Answer (score 4):

> However, if I call event.preventDefault() on the keydown event the
>   keypress and keyup events never occur.

You didn't cancel the **events themselves**, you just cancelled the **browser default actions (i.e. the *default registered event handlers*)** with preventDefault - which is exactly what you wanted - but you now want to specify your own keyup and/or keypress ***event handler***, right? The events keyup and keypress are still there, it's just that they probably have no event handlers. Perfect! So now of course "nothing happens" - *you* took the default event handlers out like you wanted to for "keydown" event, and there were probably no other event handlers registered to the keyup and keypress events so there were no more actions (handlers) to fire anymore!

So from your same event keydown handler, right after you call `event.preventdefault()`, you can say `$('#whatever').on('keyup',function(){console.log('key is up now')})` for example. I mean just bind keyup directly now from same keydown handler to whatever function you desire and I believe that when key goes up it should actually fire that function (i.e. event handler) that you bound to that event.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit late in following up. Anyways, I was a bit quick, the keyup event does occur when the key is released even if I call event.prevetDefault(), but the keypress event never occurs. I have handlers for keydown, keyup and keypress. (The reason I want to catch the keypress event is because that event has the 'charCode' property while keydown only has the 'keyCode').

Comment: Some code example would help, but I think that manually invoking the keypress event from the keyup event might be the solution for you. from the key up handler, do myjQueryElement.trigger("keypress")